# React js : Pass props to React Router's Link component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

Hey I am trying to redirect after fetch data to another and i am able to redirect but when i used `this.props.location.state` this in result page its shows like this `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` in console here is my all code , please where is the error in this code .
**Search.js**

```
async handleSubmit(e) {
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem("Token");
    try {
      const from = e.target.elements.from.value;
      const to = e.target.elements.to.value;
      const selections = [...e.target.elements.selectOptions.options].filter(
        opt => opt.selected
      );
      const selectedValues = selections.map(opt => opt.value);
      const selectedString = selectedValues.join(",");
      e.preventDefault();
      const res = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/1/deliveries/report/?date__lte=${to}&date__gte=${from}&user=${selectedString}`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(authToken)
          }
        }
      );
      const movie = await res.json();
      console.log(movie);
      this.setState({
        movie
      });
      // this.props.history.push("/driverreport");
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: "/driverreport",
        state: movie
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

and in `result.js` i am just checking data in console but i m getting data like this`
 **result.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
class DriverReportt extends Component {
render() {
    const { report } = this.state;
    const { t } = this.props;
    console.log("Don" + this.props.location.state);
    // const { car } = this.props.location;
    // console.log("car " + car);
    return (
<div></div>
)}}

export default withRouter(DriverReportt);
```

Comment: can you share code in sandbox?

Comment: here is `https://gist.github.com/iamrraj/7ba899134b3fb10bb3171389d65a2a21` gist link of both page @VahidAkhtar

Comment: Have you tried accessing it with `this.props.location.state.movie`?

Comment: Yeah i tried @VahidAkhtar